# Unable to patch object inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python. I would like to write an unit test for the following function:

```
from common.ds_factory import DSFactory
class MyClass:

def load(self, parsed_file_key):

    ds = DSFactory.getDS()

    ...
```

Now I am unable to mock `DSFactory` using `@patch(my_class.DSFactory)` as I am using  `DSFactory` inside the function.

Comment: Show us the code inclucing the source / import of `DSFactory` and the filename.

Comment: Lets assume `my_class` is in the file `ds.py` then try something like this `@patch(ds.DSFactory)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to patch `DSFactory` for *module* that uses it. As mentioned in comments, assuming `MyClass` is defined in file `my_module.py` you patch it by using module name: `@patch("my_module.DSFactory")`.

There's a catch - your module has to be importable, so it requires you to create modules.